# Get output of executed windbg command

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, dbgeng

IDebugControl::Execute method enables executing debugger commands. 
How can I get the output of the executed debugger command?
My aim is to check if a driver is loaded, to accomplish that I use Execute to execute the "lm" windbg command and parse the returned output.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement IDebugOutputCallbacks  for a sample take a look at remmon  out.cpp and out.hpp in windbg sdk sample (iirc new sdks don't contain samples you need to get it from msdn sample gallery online )

```
class StdioOutputCallbacks : public IDebugOutputCallbacks
{
public:
............
}

StdioOutputCallbacks g_Callback;

status = g_Client->SetOutputCallbacks( &g_Callback );
```

a sample dummy implementation  copy the two file out.cpp and out.hpp to the local folder build and execute to show a warning and the output of .echo execution

```
//error,relasese() omitted Do_Nothing_sample no proc|thread warn print exit; 
#include <engextcpp.hpp>
#include "out.hpp"
#include "out.cpp"
extern StdioOutputCallbacks g_OutputCb; 
void __cdecl main( void ){
    IDebugClient*   g_Client = NULL;
    IDebugControl*  g_Control= NULL;
    DebugCreate( __uuidof(IDebugClient), (void**)&g_Client );
    g_Client->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDebugControl), (void**)&g_Control );
    g_Client->SetOutputCallbacks( &g_OutputCb );
    g_Control->Execute( DEBUG_OUTCTL_THIS_CLIENT, 
  ".echo hello iam alive and kicking", DEBUG_EXECUTE_DEFAULT);  
}
```

result of build and execution

```
    3 files compiled
    1 executable built

WARNING: The debugger does not have a current process or thread
WARNING: Many commands will not work
hello iam alive and kicking
```

Comment: I still have the samples installed in `Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\sdk\samples` but I can't remember if that comes from the `Debugging tools for windows` or the `windows SDK` itself...

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your client (`IDebugClient*`) and your control (`IDebugControl*`) instances, from the client instance you need to call [`IDebugClient::SetOutputCallbacks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556751(v=vs.85).aspx) method which sets the [output callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560116(v=vs.85).aspx#output_callbacks). You need to set the output callback **before** calling the `execute()` method.

This should look like this:

```
StdioOutputCallbacks g_OutputCb;

// ...

g_Client->SetOutputCallbacks(&g_OutputCb);
g_Control->Execute(DEBUG_OUTCTL_ALL_CLIENTS,"lm vm", DEBUG_EXECUTE_ECHO);
```

Your output callback must inherit from [`IDebugOutputCallbacks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550801(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
class StdioOutputCallbacks : public IDebugOutputCallbacks
```

The simple way to do this is to copy and use directly the `out.cpp` and `out.hpp` files - present in some samples - that implements the callback class, for ex. in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\sdk\samples\dumpstk
```

The output itself is done in [`IDebugOutputCallbacks::Output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550815(v=vs.85).aspx) implementation:

```
STDMETHODIMP
StdioOutputCallbacks::Output(
    THIS_
    _In_ ULONG Mask,
    _In_ PCSTR Text
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Mask);
    fputs(Text, stdout);
    return S_OK;
}
```